# Is secondary stress important in German?

Tags: phonetics

Almost every German phonetic book points out the presence of the secondary stress, yet unlike English I do not see most dictionaries including Duden, PONS, Oxford, Larousse among many others refer to it in the phonetic writing. I can imagine that some syllables must have a secondary stress since they do not have a primary stress and can not be reduced to schwa as well as they are originally the main stems in other words. Examples:

Ein**teil**ung, Hoch**haus**, Autoge**schäft**, aus**werf**en etc.

Do the previous syllables **in bold** have secondary stress? Is secondary stress important in German in the first place? Why do not dictionaries mention it like English dictionaries do?

Comment: You should correct *Auto**geschäft*** to *Autoge**schäft** since *ge* is definitely the syllable with the least stress - Au(1)-to-ge-schäft(2). *Au* is first, *schäft* is second. Similarly aus(1)-wer(2)-fen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me as a native speaker: yes, longer German words have syllables with secondary stress, and it is important to put the correct stress (pimary and secondary) on the right syllable.

Test:

> Au(1)-to-ge-schäft(2)

is correctly pronounced. Whereas

> *Au(1)-to-ge(2)-schäft

is a technically possible way of pronouncing this word, but it is definitely wrong. It sounds as if the person speaking was from Russia or Hungary. (Both have their peculiar and separate problems with finding the correct syllables to stress in German.)

Similarly

> Ein(1)-tei(2)-lung

is correct, whereas

> *Ein(1)-tei-lung(2)

sounds completely idiotic, and I can even not imagine a native speaker of what language would be in danger of pronouncing it this way. If any, it would be something as far away as Mandarin.

You can do this test with every longer word: Rattenschwanz, Gebührenordnung, Feuerwehrleiter, Hundekacke, Kamelhaarjacke, Suppenschüssel, Oxymoron, Ausspracheregel, Poesiealbum, Onomatopoeie, Auspuffmuffe...

**Later thoughts: is there a '*potential* secondary stress'?**

After some more in-depth discussion in the comments e.g. around words such as *Stadtrundfahrt*, as well as with respect Janka's separate answer, I would admit that it can justifiably be claimed that *Stadtrundfahrt* can also be seen as having one single syllable stress (*Stadt(1)-rund-fahrt), i.e. one can see the other syllables as equally unemphasised.

However, there seems to be at least a **potential secondary stress bearing syllable**; which becomes visible as soon as one tries to put a secondary stress on one of the remaining syllables. Put it on the wrong syllable, and you get a clear mistake: *Stadt(1)-rund-fahrt(2)*, whereas put on the correct syllable, everything sounds okay: *Stadt(1)-rund(2)-fahrt.

Consequently I would instroduce here the term of a "crypto-secondary stress location", "hidden secondary stress location", or "potential secondary stress location".

Comment: I'm a bit wary about *-geschäft* which gets reduced very much in southern dialects. If there is any stress on it, it seems to be by purpose to me.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann Thank you, it was only a mistake due to rush. Of course, neither ge- nor ver-/er-/be-/zer-... has a stress.

Comment: @Janka   Dort wo man nicht "Schuhgeschäft" sondern "Schuhgschäft" sagt (also etwa im schönen Schwabenland), gibt es ja auch keine dritte Silbe, die den Sekundärakzent fälschlicherweise abbekommen könnte. "Gschäft" ist einfach nur ein einzige Silbe. Aber beim "Gschäftleshuber" ist die Aussprache als *Gschäft(1)-les-hu(2)-ber* (und nicht anders!) trotzdem wichtig.

Comment: Gut erklärt. . .

Comment: Where is the secondary stress in 'Stadtrundfahrt'? Is it right when a primary stress 'Stadt' immediately preceeds a secondary stress 'rund', then the secondary stress moves to right and thus in 'fahrt' instead of 'rund'?

Comment: Both *Stadt-* and *-rund-* are prefixes. The stem is *-fahrt*.

Comment: @Abdullah  Correct distribution of stresses is *Stadt(1)-rund(2)-fahrt*. - Probe: *Stadt(1)-rund-fahrt(2)* would sound odd. I admit that this is a difficult case. Additional observation: *Rundfahrt* is correctly pronounced *Rund(1)-fahrt*, not *Rund-fahrt(1)*.

Comment: Sounds like your answers are contradicting

Comment: @Abdullah  Contradicting in what? - I so far only gave correct pronunciations. I did not claim I knew a rule or so for this.

Comment: Christian is right, but it's hard to make out a pattern in this.

Comment: I thought Janka has said the secondary stress is on 'fahrt', but you have said it is better to be on 'rund'

Comment: I wouldn't apply secondary stress at all.

Comment: @Abdullah   Yes, that's interesting. But Janka did not say where the stress is, she only presented an idea about prefixes and word stems.

Comment: That's ok, I don't need rules, and I am very grateful 

Comment: Ok, that clears everything up, thank you a lot both. You have been so helpful.

Comment: @Janka   I admit that it is also a viable argument to claim that *Stadtrundfahrt* has only primary stress, and no secundary. But *if* you want to place a secondary, it would be on *rund*.

Comment: @Abdullah   It was a good and well-put question.

Comment: By the way, if you always stress the end the words, you'll sound Swiss.

Comment: @Janka   I gluub, **ä**sisch n**e**tdie l**ä**tschte, **ä**sisch v**i**elmähr die **ä**rschte S**i**lbe!

Comment: Ah! So läuft das.

Answer (score 0):

Secondary stress is used on the stem if the primary stress is put on the prefix instead by purpose. For example, the natural pronounciations are:

> 'Teilung → 'Ein"teilung
>
> 'werfen → 'aus"werfen

It's pretty common to use stress to distinguish separable verbs from their inseparable counterparts:

> fahren → 'um"fahren  (*Sie 'fuhr den Pylon 'um.*)
>
> fahren → um'fahren  (*Sie um'fuhr den Pylon.*)

Your other two examples *Hochhaus* and *Autogeschäft* do not have "natural" secondary stress. Just don't put any stress on reduction syllables as *-ge-* in *Autogeschäft*. (You may of course apply your own stress pattern to point out parts of the word.)